# User Provisioning for Yammer

Tags: c#-4.0

I am building a third party webapplication which will create automatically create users in Yammer service.For this I need to use the API of yammer,which requires a authentication mechanishm OAUTH,which send the authorised code to some redirect url which is not a feasible solution .Can any one out here help me to Access API but any other means?

Thanks in advance
Namrata

Comment: Can you explain why it is not a feasible solution to use the Yammer API as it exists? Yammer requires OAUTH for authentication, there's no way around that part.

Comment: Since I am building a connector I will be trying to access your API,when i do so if I give a redirect URL my code cannot go to the URL n fetch the value.Hence i said its not a feasible solution for me.Can you let me know how do i get permanent ID's to access API's